# onSubmit in apps script embedded in the new google site suddenly has issues

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sites

A google apps script embedded in new google sites was working fine until recently.  In my code, the doGet method is used to load the form (which works fine).

On clicking the "submit" button, the handleFormSubmit function is used to save data  (which also works fine) and then then the form is supposed to redirect to a confirmation page (Thanks.html) which is where the issue is.

This confirmation page opens when I test the script as a standalone webApp but has stopped opening when script is embedded in google site. So, when I click Submit, all the data is saved as intended but the Thanks.html does not open.

I ran the script as standalone WebApp and it works fine. So, I am not really able to do anything else. I want to know if Google Sites recently made any changes which could have made some part of my code incompatible?

```
 \*Index.html*\

        <form id="keyForm" onsubmit="handleFormSubmit(this)" action="<?= action ?>" method="post"> 


  \*doGet*\
    function doGet(e){ 

      var html= HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('index')
      html.action = ScriptApp.getService().getUrl();
      return html.evaluate;

    }


    \*doPost*\

    function doPost(e) {
      var html= HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Thanks.html');
      html.name = e.parameter.name;
       return html.evaluate;
    }
```

index.html contains the template for the form, which is loading properly.
'action' is a variable in the index.html which is set in the doGet function.

After form load, there is a submit button and onclick of this button, data should be saved (working fine) and a new page thanks.html should open (not working if code embedded in google sites).

Answer (score 0):

### I recommend you the following solution:

Instead of pasting a Google Form directly into your Google Sites website, embed an HTML code block.

This HTML script should call your Google Form by its URL and embed it in an Iframe. You specify in the `<script>` part with `onload`  what should happen on submit - e.g. open your "Thank You" page - accessed by its URL.

Here is a sample snippet:

```
<iframe id="gform" src="URL of your Google Form" width="SPECIFY" height="SPECIFY" frameborder="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" style="margin:0 auto; max-width:100%;">Loading…</iframe>

<script type="text/javascript">
var load = 0;

document.getElementById('gform').onload = function(){
    /*Execute on every reload on iFrame*/
    load++;
    if(load > 1){
        /*Second reload is a submit*/
        document.location = "URL OF YOUR THANK YOU PAGE";
    }
}
</script>
```